# Computer doesn't start, infinite loop of on and off

Tags: windows, bsod

Yesterday I removed my headset from my PC (Corsair Vengeance 1500) and I got a BSOD. after that I told my PC to go back to latest stable version of Windows and got another BSOD after starting my PC:

[image: BSOD]

After that a friend of mine told me to remove the BIOS battery and push the power button for 20~30 seconds.

When I did this, my pc would start, however only for a couple of seconds (and while my monitor was connected, I did not get any response from my pc towards the monitor, it stayed being black), then shuts off and somehow magically turn on again and this process repeats itself (loop).

It seems like my problem is kind of explained in the following question:

[My computer doesn't start - it is stuck in a turn-on, turn-off loop](https://superuser.com/questions/556288/my-computer-doesnt-start-it-is-stuck-in-a-turn-on-turn-off-loop)

But I wonder if I can replace my PSU with any Wattage PSU to check if it's my PSU causing this problem. I would like to know if any of you could help me further with this issue.

**What I tried so far:**

- Remove RAM, Hard drive, SSD, Graphics card, so that only my PSU is
  connected to the motherboard, CPU and fans. The problem still occurs
  (which makes me think it has something to do with motherboard, CPU or
  PSU.
- Getting a new BIOS Battery and replace old one (tried this and seems like this wasn't the cause anyways).
- I found the following link as manual to my motherboard, I guess I should try to clear CMOS aswell (page 26): ftp://download.gigabyte.ru/manual/mb_manual_ga-z87x-d3h_e.pdf

**Things I could try:**

- Buy a cheap PSU/Motherboard to see which of the two is causing trouble.

**Computer specs:**

- Intel Core i5 4670K
- Gigabyte GA-Z87X-D3H
- Seagate Barracuda 7200.14 ST1000DM003, 1TB
- Corsair Vengeance LP CML8GX3M2A1600C9
- XFX 550W Pro
- Crucial m4 CT128M4SSD2 128GB

Comment: I'm guessing your OS is installed to your SSD? Do you know if your EFI System Partition is on your SSD or HDD? This symptom is often when it's having trouble reading the boot EFI partition correctly, often linked to a faulty drive or file corruption somewhere.

Comment: It looks like you have accidentally created two accounts. You can [contact the team](http://stackoverflow.com/contact) to have them merged, which will allow you to regain direct editing privileges on your contributions.

Comment: I've added the specs from the answer into the question for you.

Comment: I have my OS installed on my SSD. I'm not sure how to answer the second question, I think everything concerning my OS is installed on my SSD.

Comment: Does your computer *attempt* to boot with the HDD connected and the SSD disconnected?

Answer (score 1):

Since I experienced the same problem several times I'm guessing it could be the faulty RAM module. Maybe you can try booting the Computer with a Linux live system so that you can be sure whether it is a Software or Hardware related issue.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: OP posted this comment "I can't boot my pc up to the boot menu, how am I supposed to even install and or start in Linux then? I don't have much experience with linux besides installing it on a virtual machine." as an answer due to an account mix up.